# rails: what are activeadmin 'comments on resources'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

When you first install activeadmin on a rails application, there is a tab called "Comments" in the /admin dashboard.

I'm surprised to see this, because I don't have a table as such in my database.

What is this for exactly? The documentation says

> By default Active Admin includes comments on resources. Sometimes,
>   this is undesired.

Can someone elaborate what's meant by 'comments on resources'

Answer (score 5):

AA provides the possibility to add comments to each resource. 
Like `has_many :comments`, but only available in AA panel.

I usually disable the comments, but it depends - sometimes they are useful.

There are some setting in `config/active_admin.rb`:

```
  # You can completely disable comments:
  config.comments = true
  #
  # You can disable the menu item for the comments index page:
  config.show_comments_in_menu = false # if set to false you won't see the tab Comments
  # You can change the name under which comments are registered:
  # config.comments_registration_name = 'AdminComment'
```

Comment: i was hoping the answer would address the question : "What is this for exactly"

Comment: I don't think there is an answer to "what is this for exactly" since they are just there as a part of gem's functionality.

Comment: in what scenario would someone add a comment (use case)

Answer (score 0):

As we know already that the Active Admin is used to control many of the website related things from backend with ease, the comments section is also the use case in that.

Once we add any comments on any of the records from the active admin, we can see those comments in one place. As sometimes the admin wants to add a comment for a specific user that describes any user quality, then we can use that.

[image]

[image]